# PayPal Plus / PHP SDK – pay with bank account / debit card

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am developing a small custom payment with the Paypal PHP SDK. The payment methods "paypal", "creadit card" and "invoice" are working fine. But I don't get how to implement the "direct debit" payment with the PHP SDK.

In the docs (http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/docs/class-PayPal.Api.Payer.html) is the method `setPaymentMethod()` defined with the possible value "bank". But I cannot find the "bank card funding instrument" to set the debit card to pay with (http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/docs/class-PayPal.Api.FundingInstrument.html)

I think I need a debit card as funding instrument – with the debit card number (in my case in germany the "IBAN").

Answer (score 0):

You'll get an "approvalURL" as a result of the Create Payment response (for this I use the Paypal PHP SDK).

With this "approvalURL" you must setup the "payment wall" (it is the actual payment selection frame vom PayPal - you must include a js-Script and define a placeholder for the payment wall). Then it is rendered on demand and based on the "approvalURL".

Depending on the billing address country a buyer will see all available funding sources for his country.

That's all - you can take it step by step with the help of the following guide (page 16): [PayPal-Integration-Guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/de_DE/downloads/PayPal-PLUS-IntegrationGuide.pdf) (date of download: 28.02.2017)

I hope, it'll help you to come along!